# Sitesearch tracking in GA4 using GTM

Tags: search, typo3, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, typo3-extensions

I need some help with my adjustments in Google Tag Manager (GTM). Until now I can not see the value of the customer search term in Google Analytics 4 (GA4).

**Relevance**

After the big announced Google-Update to GA4, there is no possibility to insert special characters within the search parameters. This leads to problems when using extensions in TYPO3 e.g. [ke_search](https://docs.typo3.org/p/tpwd/ke_search/5.0/en-us/Statistics/GoogleAnalytics.html)

The searchterm accures in the URL e.g. `example.de/suche?tx_kesearch_pi[sword]=test`

As it is not possible to use our (TYPO3) search parameter `tx_kesearch_pi1[sword]` in Google Analytics 4 (GA4), we have to use GTM to administrate an event for the searchterms on our website. (Another option would be to rename the parameter in TypoScript. In this case it is requested to solve it in GTM).

**Approach:**

To track the search term I created a **new Tag** called "GA-4 Searchterm". The Tag-Type is an GA4-Event and the configuration is based on the GA page view tag (All pages). As Event-Name I used `search` as it is [recommended from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en&ref_topic=13367566&sjid=13616847833556290485-EU#). As Event-Parameter I use `search_term` as it is [recommended as well](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?hl=de&client_type=gtm#search). The value is my variable, which I will describe below.

[image]

The next step is the **trigger**.
The Trigger is running well, as I checked it with a few tools. As we have some more domains with differend languages, i used Regex. The Type is a "page view" which will be fired when the page url agrees with the Regex. The value here are my url-pages e.g. example.com/search. So I used the landingpage-name `suche|search|buscar|recherche|ricerca`

Again: The Trigger is working well for every language.

[image]

Okay, now the **variable**, where I think is a mistake in the adjustment. I'm using URL and query as type. For my search-key I´m using my parameter `tx_kesearch_pi1[sword]`

[image]

**Steps in GA4:**

In GA4 I have created a User Defined Definition.
[image]

Now I can see that Analytics counts the retrieved event `search_term` but I can not see the value of it e.g. Test-Search.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?
Thanks for your support!

Comment: Have a look into the docs on how to adjust the query parameter: https://docs.typo3.org/p/tpwd/ke_search/5.0/en-us/Statistics/GoogleAnalytics.html

Comment: Hi Bernd, thanks for your comment and the editing. This way is out of date. You still can add query in Analytics, but if you try it with tx_kesearch_pi1[sword] you get an error message. I mentioned it above.  So we want to solve it by GTM.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works!
Please do the following:

1. Add a Custom Definition:
   [Custom Definitio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcuHH.png)
2. Add a Data Exploration:
   [Data Exploration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yywMX.png)

Have fun :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).